# What happens when same library is linked dynamically and statically to a c++ program?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I came across code where a library is linked statically and shared ,and both contains function names also same .How does does linker decide which library to link.
I  am adding foobar.so library executable path here in this path /etc/ld.so.conf aswell as -I /(include files path) -l(executable name) -L(library executable path )
.After this i executed ldconfig  .I am using gcc comipler version gcc (GCC) 4.4.7

Comment: Which linker and which OS and what command line was used for linking?  Such details can change the answer significantly.  But the typical answer is the linker uses the first library containing a symbol that it sees after it knows the symbol is needed.

Comment: Those are two completely different approaches, I suggest you reading around dynamic vs static linking and also get to know your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the runtime environment you are using, and how "shared" or "dynamic" libraries are implemented in that environment.

There is one approach where each dynamic library comes together with a statically linked "stub" library, so the compiler resolves your calls against the stub methods, and the stub methods forward to the dynamically loaded library once that library has been loaded.  This would definitely not work in your case, because each stub method would conflict with a statically linked method.

There is another approach where loading a dynamic library gives you a handle to that library, and then you can query the system for entry points on that handle, and invoke these entry points dynamically.  In this case, the linker is not involved at all in the resolution of the dynamic entry points, so there is no problem at all (besides it being pointless) with having a statically linked library that provides equivalent entry points.